# How to keep same width on JQM data-role=mini?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, input

While using the attribute `data-role="mini"` within a Jquery Mobile input field the text size will be small, but unfortunately the width of the input field is not the same.

E.g.:

[image]

```
<input type="checkbox" name="news" checked="checked" id="checkbox-mini-0" class="custom" data-mini="true">
<label for="checkbox-mini-0">test</label>
```

What would be the best approach to keep the width the same?

Comment: Post your HTML markup

Comment: done. I just added the data-rol="mini"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/09p2sebh/ - look to be same width to me... Can you edit the fiddle to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I could not reproduce inside your fiddle, but created another one to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/x_merlin_x/kzywsezh/4/ (by the way, I could not see any external jquery resources inside your fiddle - how did you include jquery?)

Comment: I posted an answer. In my fiddle, I clicked the JavaScript button at top right of script editor panel and selected jQuery 1.11.0, and checked jQuery Mobile 1.4.4.  I guess from 1.4.4 to 1.4.5 they added a margin to the ui-mini class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in jQM 1.4.5, the ui-mini class adds a margin to the checkbox container.  You can override it with the following CSS:

```
div.ui-mini {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Your updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kzywsezh/5/)**